# How to submit multiple identical forms with one button

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-core

I'm currently building and application in ASP.NET Core MVC and I have ran into a problem which I cannot solve.

I have a form for something and that form should contain multiple identical fields which are added dynamically (1-10). I have managed to do that by creating a ViewComponent which contains those form fields and I make an Ajax call to invoke the view component into a tab if a user chooses to add another segment of those fields.

```
    function CallViewComponent(num_tabs) {
    var data = { id: num_tabs };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Create/CreateActivityForm',
        cache: false,
        data: data
    }).done(function (result) {
        var container = "#activity-" + num_tabs;
        $(container).html(result);
    });
}
```

The problem arises because each of those fields in that view component shares a name with the other fields so each time I invoke another view component the radio buttons are shared between all identical fields.

Here is a snippet of the ViewComponent:

```
@model CreateActivityViewModel

<div class="activity-tab">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="La.OrdinalNumber">Redni broj aktivnosti</label><br />
        <select asp-for="La.OrdinalNumber" class="ordinals" style="width:50%">
            @foreach (var on in Model.OrdinalNumbers)
            {
                <option value="@on.Value">@on.Text</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="La.Latype">Tip aktivnosti</label><br />
        <select asp-for="La.Latype" class="activity-type" style="width:50%">
            @foreach (var lt in Model.LaTypes)
            {
                <option value="@lt">@lt.LatypeName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="La.Laname">Naziv aktivnosti</label>
        <input asp-for="La.Laname" type="text" name="La.Laname" placeholder="Unesite naziv aktivnosti" class="f1-activity-name form-control" id="f1-activity-name">
    </div>
```

Here is my controller which returns the ViewComponent:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateActivityForm(int id)
{
    return ViewComponent("ActivityTab", id);
}
```

Here is the Invoke method from the ViewComponent:

```
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int id)
    {
        var latypes = _laTypeRepository.GetAllLaType.ToList();
        var ordinals = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var laperformances = _laPerformanceRepository.GetAllLaPerformance.ToList();
        var teachingAids = _teachingAidRepository.GetAllTeachingAid.ToList();
        var strategyMethods = _strategyMethodRepository.GetAllStrategyMethod.ToList();
        var laCollaboration = _laCollaborationRepository.GetAllLaCollaboration.ToList();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            ordinals.Add(new SelectListItem($"{ i }. aktivnost", i.ToString()));
        }

        return View( new CreateActivityViewModel
        {
            FormId = id,
            LaTypes = latypes,
            OrdinalNumbers = ordinals,
            LaPerformances = laperformances,
            StrategyMethods = strategyMethods,
            Lacollaborations = laCollaboration,
            TeachingAids = teachingAids,
            TeachingAidUser = new List<TeachingAid>(),
            TeachingAidStudent = new List<TeachingAid>()
        });
    }
```

And finally this is where the ViewComponent gets invoked. It is inside another form because I need to submit the main form and all the ViewComponents at once:

```
           <fieldset>
            <h4>Aktivnosti</h4>
            <!-- Activity Tabs -->
            <div id='activity-tabs'>
                <!-- Activity Links -->
                <ol id="#activity-links">
                    <li><a href='#activity-1'>#1</a></li>
                    <li id="add-activity"><button type="button" id='add-activity'><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></li>
                </ol>

                <!-- Activity Content -->
                <div id='activity-1'>
                    <h3>Aktivnost #1</h3>
                    @await Component.InvokeAsync("ActivityTab")
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Navigation Buttons -->
            <div class="f1-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Prethodna</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Kreiraj scenarij</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
```

My question is how do I separate those identical forms and be able to submit them and store every single one of those forms into an array of objects which I can then store into a database.

I am open to all ideas and will change the entire code if necessary.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an array of objects you need to render the components using a FOR loop rather than a FOR-EACH. I like to push common code into a shared view but you can code direct in the view. You will need to set your asp-for attributes in order to bind values to the  model

```
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Resources.Count; index++)
{
    <partial name="_ResourceHidden" for="@Model.Resources[index]" />
```

Direct render

```
@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Resources.Count; index++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
          @Model.Resources[index].ResourceName
        </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip but the problem does not come from rendering the view components. The view components render fine and I cannot use a for or foreach loop for rendering because the components have to render dynamically (when the user presses the button). I have managed to do that. The problem here is that I have multiple identical form fields that are rendered and I have to separate them somehow but I don't know how. Should I place them in separate forms/formfields or something completely different, that is the question at hand.

Comment: If you follow what is rendered from the above example code you get something such as the following example:- <input type="hidden" data-val="true" id="Resources_2__IsVisible" name="Resources[2].IsVisible" value="True">. All you have to do is dynamically generate elements in the same format and it will work